# How To Add The Same Parameters To The Url When Refresh

Tags: javascript, url-parameters

I Have A Small Doubt
Here I set Url Like This
**www.example.com/turn.html?some_letters&for=alpha_king**
and i use a javascript like below

```js
var toRe = location.search.substring(0);
window.history.pushState("", document.title, window.location.pathname + toRe.substring(0, toRe.indexOf('&for=')));
```

to remove the &for and text after it on page load
once it reomved it looks like
**www.example.com/turn.html?some_letters**
and how to readd the same parameter with the same value (**&for=alpha_king**) to the url when a user refresh it
anyone knows please tell
Thank You

Comment: Personally I don't understand what your goal is.

Comment: So when the visitor first accesses the page you remove the `for` value from the query string and store it in history. Then when the user refreshes the same page, you want to re add that back to the URL of that page?

Comment: @imvain2 Yes, How To Like That Please Tell

Comment: Only in javascript or are you using other languages as well?

Comment: @klediooo I need The Solution For It In Only Javascript

Comment: Is this helping? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload

Comment: Not Works Any Other

Comment: The big problem there is: that you can't modify much with javascript if the user is leaving the page or reloading because it's in the nature of javascript and to protect the user. Otherwise you just could open another webpage if he is reloading and or just throw spam alerts. You could save the variable in the localStorage like Sagar Saud or using PHP Session.

Comment: Ok Any Other Solutions For This

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for but you could actually store your "for" data in local storage.

```
localStorage.for = for;
```

I hope this is what you're looking for.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can use URLSearchParams class and get, set querystrings.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams#Browser_compatibility